# Left Join Where

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

$i table: id, item_name

$t table: id, member_name, item_name

$u table: id, member_name, membership_status

I would like to

1. list all of the item_names in $i even if there aren't any in the $t table
2. plus count the number of item_names in $t
3. and then limit the count results to where membership_status = 'active' in $u.

This is what I have so far that answers the first part of my question:

```
$find_actives = mysql_query ("select $i.item_name,  
                  count($t.item_name) from $i left  
                  join $t on $i.item_name = $t.item_name group by $t.item_name")
```

But when I change it to the query below, it no longer lists ALL of the items in $i.

```
$find_actives = mysql_query ("select $i.item_name,  
                  count($t.item_name) from $i left  
                  join $t on $i.item_name = $t.item_name 
                  where $t.member_name IN (select distinct member_name from $u
                  where membership_status = 'active' group by member_name)
                  group by $t.item_name")
```

I would like the results to look like this:

item_name1 - count = 5

item_name2 - count = 0  // this is the line that goes missing

item_name3 - count = 2

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    $i.item_name,
    COUNT(temp.item_name) AS item_count
FROM $i
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT $t.item_name AS item_name
    FROM $t
    INNER JOIN $u
      ON $t.member_name = $u.member_name
    WHERE $u.membership_status = 'active'
) AS temp
  ON $i.item_name = temp.item_name
GROUP BY $i.item_name
```